# Need to read read two content simultaneously as variable

Tags: docker

I need to read below file with same label of two variables

```
 cat images_new.txt
/proj-bssf/adp-log/release/eric-data-search-engine-pm-metrics:4.0.0-23
/proj-document-database-pg/data/eric-data-document-database-bra:3.3.0-20
/proj-orchestration-so/eric-eo-api-gateway:1.0.1-41
/proj-am/releases/eric-am-common-wfs-ui:0.0.217-1
```

like need to read "/proj-bssf/adp-log/release/eric-data-search-engine-pm-metrics" as one variable and tag  4.0.0-23 as another variable

Object is two retrieve image digest information from docker private registry with a single script

Comment: Why are you telling what *you need*? You also have a *question* about it?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
while IFS=: read f v 
do
   echo "f $f"
   echo "v $v"
done < file
```

which give

```
f /proj-bssf/adp-log/release/eric-data-search-engine-pm-metrics
v 4.0.0-23
f /proj-document-database-pg/data/eric-data-document-database-bra
v 3.3.0-20
f /proj-orchestration-so/eric-eo-api-gateway
v 1.0.1-41
f /proj-am/releases/eric-am-common-wfs-ui
v 0.0.217-1
```

where

- `IFS=:` tell read to use `:` as separator

you may also use

```
cat file | while IFS=: read f v 
do
   ## more than 50 lines of code
   echo "f $f"
   echo "v $v"
done
```

- at the price os useless use of cat
- may be easyier to read if loop is long.
- this will cost me downvote.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have another qus I need to read below file as two separate variable

Comment: I have below files ..........################ cat null_image.txt
/proj-bssf/adp-log/release/eric-data-search-engine-pm-metrics
null
/proj-document-database-pg/data/eric-data-document-database-bra
3.2.0-36
##########################

Comment: I need to read it like /proj-bssf/adp-log/release/eric-data-search-engine-pm-metrics:null then next line /proj-document-database-pg/data/eric-data-document-database-bra:3.2.0-36